# What is the value of this integral?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Suppose that $f(z)=1/(b-a) ,      a≤z≤b$, and  $f(z)=0$ ,      otherwise.

Now, I want to find the following integral:
$$g(x,y)=\int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(x-z)f(y-z)dz$$

I would appreciate if you could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$\int_\mathbb R\mathbf 1_{x-b\lt z\lt x-a}\mathbf 1_{y-b\lt z\lt y-a}\mathrm dz=\int_\mathbb R\mathbf 1_{\max(x,y)-b\lt z\lt\min(x,y)-a}\mathrm dz
$$
hence
$$
g(x,y)=\frac{(b-a-|x-y|)^+}{(b-a)^2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. just a question what does + mean in your answer?

Comment: Positive part: $x^+=\max(x,0)$.

Comment: It just means: work out two cases, $x>y$ and $x \le y$, then try to find a formula that covers both cases.

Comment: @GEdgar Wrong. The two cases are $|y-x|\lt b-a$ and $|y-x|\gt b-a$, not $x\lt y$ and $x\gt y$.

Comment: I have another similar question, I dont know if I should post it as a new question. I would appreciate your help. Suppose that $f(z)=1/(b-a) ,      a≤z≤b$, and  $f(z)=0$ ,      otherwise. and $h(z)=1/(d-c) ,      c≤z≤d$, and  $h(z)=0$ ,      otherwise

Now, I want to find the following integral:
$$g(x,y)=\int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(x-z)h(y-z)dz$$

Comment: Why not using the method I showed you here?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$f(x-z)f(y-z)\neq 0\iff a\le x-z\,,\,y-z\le b\iff \begin{cases}x-b\le z\le x-a&,\;\;\text{and also}\\{}\\y-b\le z\le y-a\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{\rm g}\pars{x,y}
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{x - z}\fermi\pars{y - z}\,\dd z
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{x - y - z}\fermi\pars{-z}\,\dd z
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{-\bracks{y - x} + z}\fermi\pars{z}\,\dd z
\\[3mm]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\fermi\pars{z - \mu}\fermi\pars{z}\,\dd z
={1 \over b - a}\int_{a}^{b}\fermi\pars{z - \mu}\,\dd z
=\left.{1 \over \pars{b - a}^{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\,\dd z
\right\vert_{\mu + a\ <\ z\ <\ \mu + b}\quad
\\&\mbox{where}\quad\mu \equiv y - x
\end{align}

> 1. $\mu + b < a\quad\imp\quad{\rm g}\pars{x,y} = 0$
> 2. $a < \mu + b < b\quad\imp\quad
>            {\rm g}\pars{x,y} = \ds{\mu + b - a \over \pars{b - a}^{2}}$
> 3. $a < \mu + a < b\quad\imp\quad
>            {\rm g}\pars{x,y} = \ds{b - \mu - a \over \pars{b - a}^{2}}$
> 4. $\mu + a > b\quad\imp\quad{\rm g}\pars{x,y} = 0$

$$
{\rm g}\pars{x,y}
=\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{lcrcccl}
{b - a - \pars{x - y} \over \pars{b - a}^{2}} & \mbox{if}
& a - b & < & y - x & \leq & 0
\\[2mm]
{b - a - \pars{y - x} \over \pars{b - a}^{2}} & \mbox{if}
& 0 & < & y - x & \leq & b - a
\\[2mm]
0 & \mbox{otherwise} &&&&&
\end{array}\right.
$$

> $$\color{#00f}{\large%
> {\rm g}\pars{x,y} = {b - a - \verts{x - y} \over \pars{b -a}^{2}}
> \quad\mbox{if}\quad\verts{x - y} \leq b - a\,,\qquad
> \color{#000}{\Large 0}\quad\mbox{otherwise}}
> $$